# Are Emission and Absobtion spectrum EXACT photographic negative for Hydrogen Sample?

Tags: atomic-physics, absorption, photon-emission

If both are exact photographic negative, then is it true that the way an electron can deexcite (for eg.4$\to$1) in many ways like first 4$\to$3 and then 3$\to$1; absorption can too take place in intermediate transitions.

Answer (score 0):

In principle yes.

However suppose we take a sample of hydrogen gas and try to measure its absorption spectrum. The hydrogen atoms are going to be overwhelmingly in the ground state, so we can't observe the transition $3\to4$ because there aren't any hydrogen atoms in the $n=3$ state to absorb the light. All the atoms are in the $n=1$ state. This means that while we can see the $4\to3$ line in the emission spectrum the corresponding $3\to4$ line in the absorption spectrum isn't there.

If we excite the gas, e.g. by heating it or with an RF discharge, then we do get a significant number of atoms excited to higher energy states and in that case we can see absorption lines $2\to n$, $3\to n$, etc.

Comment: For hydrogen, $n=1$ usually means the ground state, right?

Comment: @Chris: oops, thanks, the brain is clearly not communicating with the fingers this morning :-)